# New Database and Collections Auto Drop Using RoboMongo for MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

I'm doing [this node.js tutorial](https://blog.udemy.com/node-js-tutorial/) and encountered problems when trying to create a new database and collection using Robomongo for MongoDB. It seems that any new database/collection gets automatically dropped when I add it [(see screenshot)](http://i28.photobucket.com/albums/c205/Josh_Blauvelt/mongodb_zpstvr74cvh.gif~original). I added the \data\db directory as instructed. I also downgraded Robomongo from 0.8.5 to 0.8.4 and still encounter the drop issue. One suggestion I found online was to repaired mongod.exe (mongod --repair) but that didn't help. Any clue what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It drops without me selecting or doing anything: " [conn2] CMD: drop vidzy.temp"

Comment: That's weird. Must be robomongo messing with you.

Comment: Define "repair mongod.exe wit node.js commandline", please.

Comment: I shut the service off and ran "mongd --repair"

Comment: It's a problem with Robomongo. I found a tutorial on how to use the MongoDB shell and created a test database that works. Then I opened Robomongo and the test database shows up, but when I try to add a new database via Robomongo, I encounter the same issue.